# FAQ in Magento-2?

Tags: magento2.2, php-7

I want to show faq List in frontend using accordion.And also the first faq was always opening for view when the page was loaded.How to do this?

```
<?php
    $collectionTitle = $this->getCollectionTitle();
    ?>
    <div id="element" data-mage-init='{"accordion":{"openedState": "active", "collapsible": true, "active": false, "multipleCollapsible": true}}'> 
        <?php foreach ($collectionTitle as $item): ?>  
            <div data-role="collapsible">
                <div data-role="trigger"> 
                    <span>
                        <?php echo $block->escapeHtml($item->getCategoryName()); ?>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>    

            <?php $collection = $this->getCollection($item->getId()); ?> 
            <div data-role="content">
                <?php foreach ($collection as $items): ?>             
                    <?php echo $block->escapeHtml($items->getQuestion()); ?> 
                    <?php echo $block->escapeHtml($items->getAnswer()); ?>            
                <?php endforeach; ?> 
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You need to set active:[0] for first tab active,**

```
<div id="element" data-mage-init='{"accordion":{"openedState": "active", "collapsible": true, "active": [0], "multipleCollapsible": true}}'>
```

Comment: no change in that

Comment: i have updated answer. use "active": [0]

Comment: can u give explain for this?

Comment: For activate your tab like 0 you need to pass value as array for index starting with 0. so need to keep active:[0] if you want to keep 2 tab active at a time you need to keep active:[0 1] and so on.

Comment: Wah Rakesh wah ..